# При клике на кнопку(номер телефона) выбирается приложение для звонка

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Как это реализовать? Должно быть какой то стандартный вызов такого интерфейса с передачей номера телефона

Еще интересует аналог с Email

Comment: в ios 10 будут extensions для приложения телефон, может там такой фокус получится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Звонок при нажатии на кнопку:

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1234567890"]];
}
```

2) Отправка email: [тут](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-send-email-iphone-app/) хороший урок на эту тему.